# similar to SAS where we have macro variable syslast which return the last created dataframe , do we have a similar thing in r

Tags: r

Similar to `SAS` where we have system macro variable `syslast` which returns the last created dataframe, do we have a similar thing in `r`

Comment: you can try `.Last.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the most recent returned value using `.Last.value`